# MySQL IF Statement, IF SET, ELSE do nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I always run into syntax errors on the statement below.

This what I have so far, which does not seem to work.

```
IF(birthday_year='0', birthday_year='0001', birthday_year)
```

I want it so that if the `birthday_year` value is set as 0, I want it to be 0001, otherwise (if it is NOT 0, and is a different value) keep it that value; don't change the value if it is not 0.

Comment: is it part of select statement?

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't mention. It is part of a SELECT statement. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please do not apologize for asking questions. And also do not add thank you's. These things are considered `noise` on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is simply `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`, so simply;

```
SELECT IF(birthday_year='0', '0001', birthday_year) birthday_year
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a part of the select statement, you can use:

```
   SELECT 
        CASE 
               WHEN BIRTHDAY_YEAR='0'
                    THEN '0001'
               ELSE BIRTHDAY_YEAR
        END AS COLUMN_NAME 
   FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your table schema, you may need to use integers instead of strings:

```
SELECT IF(birthday_year=0, 0001, birthday_year) FROM someTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table, here's what you do:

```
UPDATE table1 SET birthday_year = '0001' 
WHERE birthday_year = '1'
```

You really only use the `IF` statement inside stored procedures.

See: [google](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=mysql%20stored%20procedures&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3anl%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Nl9lU6HIC6nd8geO-YCwCg)
More specifically: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843

Whilst you can use the `IF` statement in a `select` it really does not make much sense. You'd rather use a `where` or `case` clause instead.